# ko observableArray updates, but bound select list not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I'm somewhat new to using Knockout, and I've run into an problem. I've got search functionality that returns JSON data and updates an observableArray which populates a select list. I've got it loading a default set on initial load, and then you can search on keyword text, it makes a web api call and it updates the observableArray. This all works, but the select list doesn't update. I'm sure I'm just missing something simple, but haven't been able to figure out what it is. I've created a fiddle that reproduces what I'm doing with the same lack of results.

Here's the HTML:

```
<button href="#" data-bind="click: updateSearch">Search</button><br/>
<select data-bind="options: customerResults, 
                   optionsText: function(item) {
                                return item.Name
                            }, 
                   value: selectedCustomer,
                   optionsCaption: '- Please Select -', 
                   valueUpdate: 'change'" size="15">
</select>
```

Here's the JS:

```
    $(function () {

    var custResult = function(Id, Name, Address1, City, State) {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Address1 = Address1;
        this.City = City;
        this.State = State;
    };

// Test data for initial binding    
var data = [
        new custResult(1, "Test1", "123 Fake St", "Springfield", "VT"),
        new custResult(2, "Test2", "123 Fake St", "Springfield", "VT"),
        new custResult(3, "Test3", "123 Fake St", "Springfield", "VT"),
    ];

// Test data for rebinding
var data2 = [
        new custResult(1, "TestA", "123 Fake St", "Springfield", "VT"),
        new custResult(2, "TestB", "123 Fake St", "Springfield", "VT"),
        new custResult(3, "TestC", "123 Fake St", "Springfield", "VT"),
        new custResult(1, "TestD", "123 Fake St", "Springfield", "VT"),
        new custResult(2, "TestE", "123 Fake St", "Springfield", "VT"),
        new custResult(3, "TestF", "123 Fake St", "Springfield", "VT"),
    ];

    var viewModel = {
        customerResults: ko.observableArray(data),
        selectedCustomer: ko.observable(),
        updateSearch: function () {
            this.customerResults = null;
            this.customerResults = data2
            alert("item " + this.customerResults.length.toString() + " = " + this.customerResults[this.customerResults.length - 1].Name.toString());
        },
        nameVisible: ko.observable(true)
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Here's the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/bsdavey/4M2Rh/

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I have a suggestion, instead of trying to swap arrays as the observable, how about remove and repopulate 'data', I am also new to KO, and as I understand it, removing from data and repopulating would cause it to update the select list. Have you tried that already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the updateSearch function.

When you use observable (or observableArray), you should set it as follow :

```
this.customerResults(data2);
```

If you set the observable as above, KO will be notified that the observableArray and it KO will refresh the view. Otherwise, if you reassign the property (`this.customerResults = data2`) you 'lose' the array which is bound to the view.

[**See updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4M2Rh/5/)

Comment: I'd swear I had it that way at one point and it hadn't worked, but I just changed it in my fiddle and it works perfectly now. Thanks!

Comment: @Brian Davey May be a cache problem.

Comment: Actually, it gets better. It turns out my real problem that I was encountering my actual code was different. I had customerResults being set in a $.getJson function, so when I called this.customerResults(data), it failed. I needed to call viewModel.customerResults(data).